# DSpace 7.6 - Entity type as person and project was working fine, but now doesn't anymore

Tags: tomcat, project, dspace

I am working on DSpace 7.6 and I had active entity type in collection as:

Person
OrgUnit
Project.

It was working fine, while every time I added collection as Person for example, restart the tomcat, and then add an item to the person collection, it give me a person form.

Now, this doesn't work anymore, and every time I add an item to collection of Person or Project or any type, it give me the default Publication form.

Restart Tomcat and Solr and Server do not solve the problem.

Any help?

I expect to have a person form or project form when I choose that collection type of person or project.